# Mongoid: before_destroy and Paranoia

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Is there some callbacks for soft deleting in Mongoid? Because `before_destory` won't be triggered.

Now I thought I can use `before_update` but it looks not so clear solution as I want and it is not triggered as well

```
class Message
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paranoia
  before_update :some_action

private

  def some_action
    if self.deleted_at_changed?
      ... # do my stuff
    end
  end
end
```

So the only solution is to call it from destroy action in controller?

Answer (score 2):

Mongoid supports paranoid documents.

What you do is include the Paranoia mixin:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paranoia
end
```

Then observe the following new features:

```
person.delete # Sets the deleted_at field to the current time.
person.delete! # Permanently deletes the document.
person.destroy! # Permanently delete the document with callbacks.
person.restore # Brings the "deleted" document back to life.
```

You can find this information in the extra part of the documentation on the mogoid website [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/extras.html#paranoia).

Answer (score 2):

What I did is:

```
def delete_with_callbacks
  run_callbacks(:destroy) { delete_without_callbacks }
end
alias_method_chain :delete, :callbacks
```

Answer (score 1):

As Tyler mentioned, you can use `Mongoid::Paranoia`. This will give you another option ::

```
message.remove
```

To check to see if it has been deleted or not, you can use `message.destroyed?`.

Also `Message.deleted` would fetch you all the Soft Deleted (removed) records from class Message.

Visit their beautiful [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Paranoia#remove-instance_method) along with this [one](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Paranoia/ClassMethods#).